# Android ImageView show image by path

Tags: java, android, sqlite, imageview

I'm making an app that stores image path in SQLite. Then we open new Activity and it should show image from database. Database is working fine, I tested if I get result (path) and it works (tested with toast, see below), but I can't make it show image in ImageView, it's always blank. Here is some of code I have:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slikatest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is activity class that shows layout:

```
public class SimpleViewExample extends AppCompatActivity {

DBAdapter db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pogled);

    db = new DBAdapter(SimpleViewExample.this);

    db.openDB();

    Cursor c = db.getOneImage(1);
    c.moveToFirst();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slikatest);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(c.getString(2));

    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   }
}
```

Toast returns result like : `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/example.png`

Any help is welcome. Thanks it advance!

**UPDATE:**

Looks like I have problem with premissions , found this error in logcat:
`open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` .

Any idea how to fix this ?

**FIX:**

I'm so dumb, sorry. I just had to go in Settings -> Applications -> My app -> allow premission to use memory.

Sorry, have fun

Comment: Why do you need to store image path in database? You want cache your image for faster loading time?

Answer (score 1):

Include permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As you said your `c.getString(2)` return image path.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pogled);

    db = new DBAdapter(SimpleViewExample.this);

    db.openDB();

    Cursor c = db.getOneImage(1);
    c.moveToFirst();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


File imagefile = new  File(c.getString(2));

if(imagefile.exists()){

    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slikatest);

    img.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

}
}
```

Comment: `if(imagefile.exists())` , this looks really handy , thanks. +1.

Comment: if this is the solution then please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

img.setBackgroundResource(bitmap);

instead of

img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

Just had to give premissions in Settings -> Applications -> then select my installed app -> Premissions - > allow use of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing on Android 6.0+ you have to manage runtime permissions further to add permission in Manifest as described above.

[Android runtime permissions guidance](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Here below the code that worked for me (Android 7.0):

1. After having stored the path as String in the db (in my case using ContentValues), I retrived in a custom CursorAdapter class, bindView method using:

   ```
   ImageView prodImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_img);

   int picColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PIC);


   String prodPathPic = cursor.getString(picColumnIndex);

   File f = new File(prodPathPic);

   Bitmap imgBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
   prodImageView.setImageBitmap(imgBmp);

   }
   ```

   2. To make it works I added in onCreate() method in my main activity the following code to ask the users the access permission to internal memory:

.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```

Hoping that this will help you